# How to connect to a oracle remote database from a java application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to make a java application that connects to a database that is not located on my pc. I'm not sure how to do this. If I create my own database with MySQL, where do i need to store the database in order to acces it from other computers. I want to know what do I need in order to do this. I checked the internet and saw a lot of examples using jdbc and connecting to a url with localhost or something like this. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of connecting to `localhost`, you have to put the remote host name or ip address,  That's about it.

Comment: 1) you need to bind MySQL to the correct interface to allow remote access. 2) you need a user in MySQL that is allowed to connect remotely. 3) you need configure jdbc to connect to you remote server by specifying its IP address rather than localhost.

Comment: @PeterLawrey And I have to store the database in some place? For example, I create the database on my pc using my local instance from MySQL with localhost3306... How Can I connect to this database from other pc? Where is it stored?

Comment: Why does it matter where it's stored? MySQL is a **server**, it runs on a computer and exposes port `3306` for connect (if correctly configured). JDBC on _any other computer_ connects to port `3306`.

Comment: It is stored on your file system, in a directory somewhere, but you don't need to know this to connect to it. You need to replace `localhost::3306` with `{your-host-name}:3306` Only you know what you hostname is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local: the server address will be 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'
You can install mysql on your computer and connect to it with the computer's ip (generally 192.168.1.??). You can install LAMP or MAMP to have mysql working easily on your network ('put online' option).

Internet: the server adresse is given by your host, replace the 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' address on the jdbc parameters.

Comment: And do i need a server for that?I don't really understand how does MySQL works. Could you explain the process for me please?I mean, i want to create the database from a pc and then i want to have acces to it from any pc at any given time.

Comment: @AlexChihaia MySQL is a server.

Comment: The principle of a 'server' is that a 'machine' was running all the time then you can connect to it at any given time, we called this a 'server' (eg a server computer). Then on this machine you can install any program that can handles connection, like 'apache' for HTTP, or 'mysql' for database, these are servers applications (on server computer).

Comment: In your case you need a computer that run everyday with mysql installed on it. But to do this at home, you need a static ip address to connect to it from external. it's not the simplest way. Else you can find a host provider that handle all this for you.

Comment: @Tokazio Managed to solve the problem. Thanks for your help!